# Multiple sprites from a class are moving attached to each other, when they should be separately

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I was making a program for asteroids, but when I got to spawning the asteroids, they were all clumped together and floating.
I want each of these asteroids to move separately in their own paths like they're supposed to

This is the code for my Asteroid class

```
class Asteroid:

    def __init__(self):
        self.ang_change = randint(1, 5)
        self.ang = randint(0, 90) * (pi / 180)
        y_values = [1, 599]
        self.sx = randint(0, 800)
        self.sy = y_values[randint(0, 1)]
        # If object spawns from the top, it moves down instead of moving up and de-spawning immediately
        if self.sy == y_values[0]:
            self.neg = -1
        else:
            self.neg = 1
        self.speed = randint(5, 10)
        self.asteroid_angle = randint(0, 80)

    def generate(self):

        self.ang += self.ang_change
        asteroid_img = pygame.image.load("sprites/asteroid.png")
        asteroid_copy = pygame.transform.rotate(asteroid_img, self.ang)
        window.blit(asteroid_copy,
                    (asteroid.sx - (asteroid_copy.get_width()) / 2, asteroid.sy - (asteroid_copy.get_height()) / 2))
```

and this is the whole code if anyone needs

```
import pygame
from math import sin, cos, pi

from random import randint

scr_width = 800
scr_height = 600
window = pygame.display.set_mode((scr_width, scr_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Asteroids")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
space_img = pygame.image.load("sprites/space.jpg")


class Ship:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = 0
        self.vel = 0
        self.angle = 0

    def draw(self):
        ship_img = pygame.image.load("sprites/ship_off.png")
        ship_img_copy = pygame.transform.rotate(ship_img, self.angle)
        window.blit(ship_img_copy,
                    (self.x - (ship_img_copy.get_width()) / 2, self.y - (ship_img_copy.get_height()) / 2))

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_w]:
            ship_img = pygame.image.load("sprites/ship_on.png")
            ship_img_copy = pygame.transform.rotate(ship_img, self.angle)
            window.blit(ship_img_copy,
                        (self.x - (ship_img_copy.get_width()) / 2, self.y - (ship_img_copy.get_height()) / 2))

    def move(self, vel):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_w]:
            vel += 1
            self.x += vel * cos(self.angle * (pi / 180) + (90 * pi / 180))
            self.y -= vel * sin(self.angle * (pi / 180) + 90 * (pi / 180))
            # So that if it leaves one side it comes from the other
            if self.y < 0:
                self.y = (self.y - vel) % 600

            elif self.y > 600:
                self.y = (self.y + vel) % 600

            elif self.x < 0:
                self.x = (self.x - vel) % 800

            elif self.x > 800:
                self.x = (self.x + vel) % 800

        if keys[pygame.K_a]:
            self.angle += 7

        if keys[pygame.K_d]:
            self.angle -= 7


class Asteroid:

    def __init__(self):
        self.ang_change = randint(1, 5)
        self.ang = randint(0, 90) * (pi / 180)
        y_values = [1, 599]
        self.sx = randint(0, 800)
        self.sy = y_values[randint(0, 1)]
        # If object spawns from the top, it moves down instead of moving up and de-spawning immediately
        if self.sy == y_values[0]:
            self.neg = -1
        else:
            self.neg = 1
        self.speed = randint(5, 10)
        self.asteroid_angle = randint(0, 80)

    def generate(self):

        self.ang += self.ang_change
        asteroid_img = pygame.image.load("sprites/asteroid.png")
        asteroid_copy = pygame.transform.rotate(asteroid_img, self.ang)
        window.blit(asteroid_copy,
                    (asteroid.sx - (asteroid_copy.get_width()) / 2, asteroid.sy - (asteroid_copy.get_height()) / 2))


class Projectiles:

    def __init__(self, x, y, angle):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.angle = angle
        self.vel = 20

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 0, 0), (self.x, self.y, 5, 5))


def redraw():
    window.blit(space_img, (0, 0))
    ship.draw()
    for asteroid in asteroids:
        asteroid.generate()
    for bullet in bullets:
        bullet.draw()

    pygame.display.update()


run = True
ship = Ship(375, 225)
bullets = []
asteroids = []
while run:
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    pygame.time.delay(35)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        if len(bullets) < 11:
            bullets.append(
                Projectiles(round(ship.x + ship.width - 6.5 // 2), round(ship.y + ship.width - 6.5 // 2), ship.angle))

    for bullet in bullets:
        if 800 > bullet.x > 0 and 600 > bullet.y > 0:
            bullet.x += bullet.vel * cos(bullet.angle * (pi / 180) + 90 * (pi / 180))
            bullet.y -= bullet.vel * sin(bullet.angle * (pi / 180) + 90 * (pi / 180))
        else:
            bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))

    if len(asteroids) < 5:
        asteroids.append(Asteroid())

    for asteroid in asteroids:
        if 800 > asteroid.sx > 0 and 600 > asteroid.sy > 0:
            asteroid.sx += asteroid.speed * cos(asteroid.asteroid_angle * (pi / 180) + 90 * (pi / 180))
            asteroid.sy -= asteroid.speed * sin(asteroid.asteroid_angle * (pi / 180) + 90 * (pi / 180)) * asteroid.neg
            if asteroid.sx < 0:
                asteroid.sx = (asteroid.sx - asteroid.speed) % 800

            elif asteroid.sx > 800:
                asteroid.sx = (asteroid.sx + asteroid.speed) % 800

        else:
            asteroids.pop(asteroids.index(asteroid))

    window.fill((0, 0, 0))
    ship.move(0)
    redraw()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 2):

When you're bitting the asteroid copy, you're not using self. All the asteroids are being drawn to the same position.

Current code:

```
window.blit(asteroid_copy,
                (asteroid.sx - (asteroid_copy.get_width()) / 2, asteroid.sy - (asteroid_copy.get_height()) / 2))
```

Change to:

```
window.blit(asteroid_copy,
                (self.sx - (asteroid_copy.get_width()) / 2, self.sy - (asteroid_copy.get_height()) / 2))
```